# How to properly structure a recursive function with a single exit?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion

I wrote a recursive function to augment pandas.DataFrame.describe. It adds kurtosis and skew as rows. It also creates a second descriptive table that transposes the first, so you get a summary of summary stats.

It works great, except I don't like writing functions with more than one exit. I tried writing it with one return statement (see commented out section), but it creates two of the transposed tables in one. Correct, but too many.

```
def get_better_desc(df, recursions: int = 1):
    '''Adds kurtosis and skew to pandas.DataFrame.describe output. And, creates
    second transposed version of this table called on itself for summary stats
    of summary stats.
    Parameters:
        df: pandas.DataFrame, or Series but its super_desc isn't so meaningful.
        recursions: integer number of times to apply recursively to create
            super_desc. Default value of 1 is all that is necessary.
    Returns:
        better_desc: pandas.Dataframe (or Series) with kurtosis and skew added.
        super_desc: pandas.DataFrame (or Series) of better_desc transposed and
            made into a better_desc itself.'''
    
    kurt = df.kurtosis()
    kurt.name = 'kurt'
    skew = df.skew()
    skew.name = 'skew'
    better_desc = df.describe().append([kurt, skew])
    
    if recursions > 0:
        super_desc = get_better_desc(better_desc.transpose(),
                                     recursions=(recursions - 1))
        return better_desc, super_desc
    else:
        return better_desc

#     if recursions > 0:
#         super_desc = get_better_desc(better_desc.transpose(),
#                                      recursions=(recursions - 1))
#     else:
#         super_desc = better_desc
    
#     return better_desc, super_desc
```

Test it out:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(1,101,100),
                        'b': np.random.randint(1,101,100)})
print(test_df)
test_better_desc, test_super_desc = get_better_desc(test_df)
print(test_better_desc)
print(test_super_desc)

#      a   b
# 0   39  95
# 1   99  97
# 2    5  10
# 3   17  42
# 4   21  13
# ..  ..  ..
# 95   7  87
# 96  87  42
# 97  26  78
# 98  13  72
# 99  19  57

# [100 rows x 2 columns]
#                 a           b
# count  100.000000  100.000000
# mean    47.420000   48.940000
# std     30.589554   30.735700
# min      1.000000    1.000000
# 25%     20.750000   20.250000
# 50%     45.000000   48.000000
# 75%     73.000000   74.500000
# max    100.000000  100.000000
# kurt    -1.200778   -1.318487
# skew     0.101958    0.060246
#        count       mean        std  min        25%       50%       75%    max  \
# count    2.0   2.000000   2.000000  2.0   2.000000   2.00000   2.00000    2.0   
# mean   100.0  48.180000  30.662627  1.0  20.500000  46.50000  73.75000  100.0   
# std      0.0   1.074802   0.103341  0.0   0.353553   2.12132   1.06066    0.0   
# min    100.0  47.420000  30.589554  1.0  20.250000  45.00000  73.00000  100.0   
# 25%    100.0  47.800000  30.626090  1.0  20.375000  45.75000  73.37500  100.0   
# 50%    100.0  48.180000  30.662627  1.0  20.500000  46.50000  73.75000  100.0   
# 75%    100.0  48.560000  30.699163  1.0  20.625000  47.25000  74.12500  100.0   
# max    100.0  48.940000  30.735700  1.0  20.750000  48.00000  74.50000  100.0   
# kurt     NaN        NaN        NaN  NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN   
# skew     NaN        NaN        NaN  NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN   

#            kurt      skew  
# count  2.000000  2.000000  
# mean  -1.259632  0.081102  
# std    0.083233  0.029495  
# min   -1.318487  0.060246  
# 25%   -1.289060  0.070674  
# 50%   -1.259632  0.081102  
# 75%   -1.230205  0.091530  
# max   -1.200778  0.101958  
# kurt        NaN       NaN  
# skew        NaN       NaN
```

Ignore the NaNs because it works fine on my real dataset and I want to focus on the structure. It got the correct structure, but when you switch to my preferred method with one exit:

```
def get_better_desc(df, recursions: int = 1):
    '''Adds kurtosis and skew to pandas.DataFrame.describe output. And, creates
    second transposed version of this table called on itself for summary stats
    of summary stats.
    Parameters:
        df: pandas.DataFrame, or Series but its super_desc isn't so meaningful.
        recursions: integer number of times to apply recursively to create
            super_desc. Default value of 1 is all that is necessary.
    Returns:
        better_desc: pandas.Dataframe (or Series) with kurtosis and skew added.
        super_desc: pandas.DataFrame (or Series) of better_desc transposed and
            made into a better_desc itself.'''
    
    kurt = df.kurtosis()
    kurt.name = 'kurt'
    skew = df.skew()
    skew.name = 'skew'
    better_desc = df.describe().append([kurt, skew])
    
#     if recursions > 0:
#         super_desc = get_better_desc(better_desc.transpose(),
#                                      recursions=(recursions - 1))
#         return better_desc, super_desc
#     else:
#         return better_desc

    if recursions > 0:
        super_desc = get_better_desc(better_desc.transpose(),
                                     recursions=(recursions - 1))
    else:
        super_desc = better_desc
    
    return better_desc, super_desc
```

it does this:

```
test_better_desc, test_super_desc = get_better_desc(test_df)
print(test_better_desc)
print(test_super_desc)

#                 a           b
# count  100.000000  100.000000
# mean    47.420000   48.940000
# std     30.589554   30.735700
# min      1.000000    1.000000
# 25%     20.750000   20.250000
# 50%     45.000000   48.000000
# 75%     73.000000   74.500000
# max    100.000000  100.000000
# kurt    -1.200778   -1.318487
# skew     0.101958    0.060246
# (       count       mean        std       min        25%        50%        75%  \
# count    2.0   2.000000   2.000000  2.000000   2.000000   2.000000   2.000000   
# mean   100.0  48.320000  28.843423  2.500000  23.625000  46.500000  72.000000   
# std      0.0   1.315219   2.224340  0.707107   3.358757   2.828427   1.414214   
# min    100.0  47.390000  27.270577  2.000000  21.250000  44.500000  71.000000   
# 25%    100.0  47.855000  28.057000  2.250000  22.437500  45.500000  71.500000   
# 50%    100.0  48.320000  28.843423  2.500000  23.625000  46.500000  72.000000   
# 75%    100.0  48.785000  29.629846  2.750000  24.812500  47.500000  72.500000   
# max    100.0  49.250000  30.416269  3.000000  26.000000  48.500000  73.000000   
# kurt     NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
# skew     NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   

#               max      kurt      skew  
# count    2.000000  2.000000  2.000000  
# mean    99.000000 -1.126157  0.192540  
# std      1.414214  0.084387  0.072183  
# min     98.000000 -1.185827  0.141498  
# 25%     98.500000 -1.155992  0.167019  
# 50%     99.000000 -1.126157  0.192540  
# 75%     99.500000 -1.096321  0.218060  
# max    100.000000 -1.066486  0.243581  
# kurt          NaN       NaN       NaN  
# skew          NaN       NaN       NaN  ,        count       mean        std       min        25%        50%        75%  \
# count    2.0   2.000000   2.000000  2.000000   2.000000   2.000000   2.000000   
# mean   100.0  48.320000  28.843423  2.500000  23.625000  46.500000  72.000000   
# std      0.0   1.315219   2.224340  0.707107   3.358757   2.828427   1.414214   
# min    100.0  47.390000  27.270577  2.000000  21.250000  44.500000  71.000000   
# 25%    100.0  47.855000  28.057000  2.250000  22.437500  45.500000  71.500000   
# 50%    100.0  48.320000  28.843423  2.500000  23.625000  46.500000  72.000000   
# 75%    100.0  48.785000  29.629846  2.750000  24.812500  47.500000  72.500000   
# max    100.0  49.250000  30.416269  3.000000  26.000000  48.500000  73.000000   
# kurt     NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
# skew     NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   

#               max      kurt      skew  
# count    2.000000  2.000000  2.000000  
# mean    99.000000 -1.126157  0.192540  
# std      1.414214  0.084387  0.072183  
# min     98.000000 -1.185827  0.141498  
# 25%     98.500000 -1.155992  0.167019  
# 50%     99.000000 -1.126157  0.192540  
# 75%     99.500000 -1.096321  0.218060  
# max    100.000000 -1.066486  0.243581  
# kurt          NaN       NaN       NaN  
# skew          NaN       NaN       NaN  )
```

I'm not sure why. Any explanations? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns two dataframes, and if you only assign it to one variable, rather than ignoring the second return, it assigns both to the variable. On the recursive call, you need to specify only the first table, the first element in the list of returns `[0]`.

```
...
if recursions > 0:
        super_desc = get_better_desc(better_desc.transpose(),
                                     recursions=(recursions - 1))[0] #<=
    else:
        super_desc = better_desc
    
    return better_desc, super_desc
```